# I have an error message: "Could not resolve reference to 'System.Drawing.Color' (defined in assembly 'Acr.UserDialogs.Interface'"

Tags: android, xamarin

In Xamarin.Forms Project when compiling with "SDK assemblies only" (for "SDK and User Assemblies" the same)  I get an error message (see error message)

I have already set "Skip assembly linking" to "System;Acr;Splat"

Why? Thank you in advance.

**1. Error message:**

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line State of suppression
Error Unexpected error in the LinkAssemblies task:
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Drawing.Color' (defined in assembly 'Acr.UserDialogs.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Splat, Version=1.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Drawing.Color
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance instance)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalType(TypeReference type)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeFields(TypeDefinition type)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   bei Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   bei Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   bei Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   bei MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    mInvoice.Android
```

**2. AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="XXXXXXXX" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="75" android:versionName="5.2.2.2">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="28" android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA.AUTOFOCUS" />
    <application android:label="mInvoice" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon_30" android:theme="@style/Theme.mInvoice">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually
>   means that the type is forwarded.

You have the `application Linker` enabled in your Xamarin.Android application project and there is a mismatch in versions between forwarded types in Xamarin.Forms and `Acr.UserDialogs.Interface`. Basically `Acr.UserDialogs.Interface` was compiled against an older version of Forms then you currently are using in your project and is a really common issue if the assembly contains C# extensions.

You can try to  disable linking for the entire application or disable linking for just the `Acr.UserDialogs.Interface` assembly.
To disable linking for just that one assembly, edit your Android application project (`.csproj`) and add the following `<AndroidLinkSkip>`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <AndroidLinkSkip>Acr.UserDialogs.Interface</AndroidLinkSkip>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Ref: Xamarin Android Linking: [AndroidLinkSkip](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)

Comment: Thanks, Jessie! Unfortunately the errors happened as early. I have tried: "<AndroidLinkSkip>Acr.UserDialogs.Interface;System;Splat</AndroidLinkSkip>". Maybe assembly names are wrong?  I don't know.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because project is too big:   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mInvoice.Android

Comment: Maybe you can delete some other codes, just leave  the necessary code, which could reproduce this question.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error trying to build on Release config (Visual Studio 2019 for Mac).

Updated Xamarin.Android to version 9.4.1.0 and problem solved!

Got the tip from this issue reported in UserDialogs repo:
https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/654#issuecomment-531406106

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Answer (score -2):

I knew its too late. But still its open. Anyways,I got it resolved by setting Linking = None in Android Options.[image]

I am using VS2017 Community edition v 15.9.22. All tools and packages are up to date. I am facing this issue when i changed the build config from Debug to Release. In Debug|Any CPU, it was working fine, and with latest nuget package of UserDialogs.

Hope this helps

Please mark if this was the solution.

Comment: turning linking off does not solve the solution